# Guava Dependency Glitch with Pig and Cassandra

Tags: java, apache-pig

I am using pig 0.11.0-cdh4.3.1 for executing a UDF which is parsing JSON and inserting results into Cassandra 2.1.6. 
Now when I add Guava as Maven dependency it throws me error while connecting Cassandra:

```
NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.withFallback
```

Its because Cassandra 2.1.6 requires Guava version 15 and above. But it picks the Guava library from Pig JAR which is added to classpath as JAR (nor in Maven). How should I tell Pig to use Guava version which is v18.0 (packed with JAR) not which is used to compile pig 0.11.0.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying you can't add Pig as a Maven dependency also? That would solve the dependency clash...

Comment: @Slanec Nope, I am adding Pig as dependency but while running UDF from Pig Shell (v0.11.0 obviously), Its not taking Guava version which I have specified in Maven.

Comment: Have you tried to exclude the dependency provided by pig?

Comment: @StephanL when I run it in local (not as a pig UDF) it works as expected but when I run it on cluster as Pig UDF after bundling it as a JAR, it throws the above error !